# regex expression for getting numbers in digit and words

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Can anyone give the regex expression of parsing numbers in digits and words.

For eg: 90 people of my country are above ninety nine years of age

I want to get **90 and ninety nine** from the above sentence

Comment: Show us what you've tried and we could help you. StackOverflow isn't a free code service.

Comment: This problem seems to go beyond regex. I doubt you can write some sort of catch-all for numbers like "ninety nine".

Comment: Are the numbers (in digits and in word format) always at the same location?